# Exclude keywords implemented by a remote library during dryrun

Tags: python, robotframework

We are validating every test case with the [dryrun](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dry-run) mode of the framework and are facing some problems in case of test cases that import a remote library.

During the dryrun the remote libraries are not running, and at the moment we would like to keep it that way. So currently our purpose is to exclude the keywords defined by the remote libraries from the dryrun.

Based on the user guide, to exclude a keyword one should use a special tag `robot:no-dry-run` on the specific keywords. Unfortunately with remote libraries it is not an option, because to add tags to the remote library keywords the `get_keyword_tags` method should be implemented. So to be able to utilize this, the remote libraries should be running.

The other option that so far seems to be possible is to create a wrapper library for each remote library. For example:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

class AWrapperLibrary():

    def __init__(self):
        self._built_in_lib = BuiltIn()

    def import_remote_library(self):
        self._built_in_lib.import_library('Remote', 'http://127.0.0.1:8271/', 'WITH NAME', 'MYLIB')

    def A_Remote_Lib_Keyword(self):
        self._built_in_lib.run_keyword('MYLIB.A Remote Lib Keyword')
```

It this case the wrapper keyword would exist during the dryrun and the remote library import won't be executed as it is an underlying library call.

As the solution above is quite an overhead, I would be interested if there is an other way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know perfect answer, but another workaround you could use. Create some dummy library that detects dry run context and for dry run shows all the required keywords, whlie when in normal tests execution context has no (one) keywords:

```
from robot.running import context


if context.EXECUTION_CONTEXTS.current.dry_run is False:
    class DryRunFixer:

        def dummy_keyword(self):
            #  just avoiding no keyword warning
            pass
else:
    class DryRunFixer:

        # keyword that exists in remote lib    
        def mocked_keyword_from_remote_library(self):
            pass
```

And now in tests use this library along with your Remote lib:

```
*** settings ***
Library    Remote    http://127.0.0.1:8271/    WITH NAME   MYLIB
Library    DryRunFixer

*** Test Cases ***
test
   Mocked Keyword From Remote Library
```

In this scenario you don't have to modify remote lib nor use wrapper library.

Another solution could be with a wrapper library, which for dry run context, returns normal (not remote) library with mocked keywords, and for test execution context will return instance of the remote library.